# How would I search for a specific word in a txt file and read the line it is on and the one below it

Tags: python

So I've got a document full of trivia questions. Here's one:

```
Category: Definitions
Question: A word like 'NASA' formed from the initials of other words is a(n) ······.
Answer: acronym
```

There are about 3000 questions and I'd like to grab a random one. How would I be able to do this and get:

```
A word like 'NASA' formed from the initials of other words is a(n) ······.
```

In a variable called question.
and then the answer to that question in another.
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What steps have you taken to solve this problem? Is there anything that you have found through searching on the internet, and have you made an attempt at writing code?

Comment: Going to level with you here Samantha. It's late here and my brain's not working. I've thought about using a word search program I've already made but I don't really see how it would actually help. I thought about numbering the questions and using a simple randint but that'd take too long. I can't really think of anything else to do.

Comment: You might be able to use the split method with "\n" and ":".

Comment: I apologize if my questions before came off as rude, @MarcoWyatt I just wanted to know the context of this problem so any response I submit is relevant to what you're familiar with/trying to use and doesn't give away the answer to a homework problem.

Comment: Not a problem. It's not homework. I don't start basic CS until next year. I do this for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`linereader`](https://pypi.org/project/linereader/) module provide efficient and easy way to access random lines in a file. Supposing your file is structured as:

```
Category: Definitions
Question: 1
Answer: 1
Question: 2
Answer: 2
Question: 3
Answer: 3
```

Here is a simple snippet to get random `Question` and `Answer` from the file:

```
from linereader import getline
from random import randint

length = 7
filename = 'a.txt'

random_number = randint(2, length-2)
line_1 = getline(filename, random_number)

if line_1.startswith('Question:'):
    line_1 = line_1.strip('Question:')
    line_2 = getline(filename, random_number+1).strip('Answer:')
else:
    line_1 = getline(filename, random_number+1).strip('Question:')
    line_2 = getline(filename, random_number+2).strip('Answer:')

print(line_1)
print(line_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If i take your file to look similar to the following:

```
Category: Category 1
Question: Question 1
Answer: Answer 1
Category: Category 2
Question: Question 2
Answer: Answer 2
Category: Category 3
Question: Question 3
Answer: Answer3
...
```

Then we can do something like the following.

If you read the file in as a list of lines:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    list_of_lines = f.readlines()
```

From this you have a list of all the lines in your document.
You can then access the questions and answers by index as the next question/answer etc would have an index of +3 to the last one.

eg for the example file above we can print question answer pairs with:

```
for i in range(1, len(list_of_line)-2, 3):
     question = list_of_lines[i]
     answer = list_of_lines[i+1]
     print(question, answer)
```

Hopefully your file looks something similar or you can use the ideas here  to apply to your specific situation

Comment: I really liked this approach. I couldn't figure out how I would randomly select a question with it though. Thanks anyway, definitely taught me something.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good method is using regex, as well as random **int**, rather than just `choice()`

```py
import random
import re
all = open(filepath).readlines()
n = random.randint(0, len(all)-1)
while not re.search("^Question: ", all[n % len(all)]):
    n += 1
n = n - len(all)
Question = all[n]
Answer = all[n+1]
```

As long as all questions begin with "Question: ", and no other line does, this should be find I think

Answer (score 0):

I would first change the text to JSON using regex, then load the JSON string to have a list of dictionaries. From there pick a random number within length of that list and get the answer key.

```py
import re
import json
import random

text = """
Category: Category A
Question: Question A
Answer: Answer A
Category: Category B
Question: Question B
Answer: Answer B
Category: Category C
Question: Question C
Answer: Answer C
Category: Category D
Question: Question D
Answer: Answer D
"""

json_string = re.sub(r'(.*):\s(.*)\n(.*):\s(.*)\n(.*):\s(.*)\n?',
                     r'{"\1":"\2","\3":"\4","\5":"\6"},', text)
data = json.loads("[" + json_string.strip().rstrip(',') + "]")

random_item = data[random.randrange(len(data))]
question = random_item['Question']
answer = random_item['Answer']

print(question, answer, sep="\n")
```

The out put may be like:

```py
Question C
Answer C
```

and may print different item in next run.